# android studio: way to make validation markers thicker?

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors

In Android Studio, is there a way to change the thickness of the error validation markers in the right gutter?  They are very thin and, for me, it is difficult to discern the colors.  They tend to all look greyish.

the result is I'm having trouble seeing which are warnings and which are errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can "change the thickness" since it is representation of the entire file - it is more like a "heat map" than a navigation tool. Making the window taller would make them "thicker" and beyond that you have display and navigation options, so that you don't need to see individual indicators.

To change what is displayed (which warnings and errors are highlighted), go to Analyze -> Configure Current File Analysis then in the pop-up click on "Configure Inspections". Here you can select which warnings and errors are indicated. You can create profiles, etc. to your liking.

For  navigation, you should be able to navigate to errors only and skip the warnings, using F2 (or shift-F2) on Mac anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I think, partly, it just takes getting used to the studio's quirks.